# Changing the default input language in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget, input-language

Is there any way to change the default input language in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

mainloop()
```

Here, when I type some text into the text widget, it is being typed in english.

What I want is to type the text in some other language.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: I am not sure, but have u tried with some german font `font =` ?

Comment: I am not aware of any font that can display german characters.

Comment: Even if there is a font that can display German characters, how can I type in some other language? I am asking this because I mentioned 'German' in my question just as an example.

Comment: Input language is an OS level setting.

Comment: Using a french keyboard I was able to type éèáàâô using keys or key combinations into your GUI.  Is your question how to generate characters not available from the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, that is my question. I don't want to use keyboard shortcuts or change the input language of my whole device. I only want to change the input language of my text widget. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

On my MacOS PC, UK Keyboard, I can use various key combinations to get German and French characters.
Alt-a: å
Alt e followed by e: é
Alt u followed by o: ö or by u: ü by a: ä by A: Ä 
Alt i followed by a: â
**Step 1** would be to experiment with that.

**2nd Option** If only a few characters are required map them to e.g. the F Keys

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text( root, width = 50, height = 20, font = ( 'Arial', 20 ) )
text.grid()

key_map =  { 'F5': 'ü', 'F6': 'ö', 'F13': 'ß', 'F14': 'á', 'F15': 'é' }
# Map the function keys to the characters required.
# f5, f6, f13, etc return the mapped characters.
# The other F keys are used for system activities from my keyboard.

def do_key( event ):
    char = key_map.get( event.keysym )
    if char:
        text.insert( tk.INSERT, char )
        return 'break'  # Stops the event being passed to the text box.

text.bind( '<KeyPress>', do_key )

root.mainloop()
```

**3rd Option** A more thorough approach may be to open a second 'keyboard' window that can send characters to the text box.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text( root, width = 50, height = 20, font = ( 'Arial', 20 ) )
text.grid()

key_map =  { 'F5': 'ü', 'F6': 'ö', 'F13': 'ß', 'F14': 'á', 'F15': 'é' }

def make_keys( char ):
    def do_key():
        text.insert( tk.INSERT, char )
        return 'break'
    return do_key

def get_key( event ):
    master = tk.Toplevel( root )
    for col, v in enumerate( key_map.values()):
        tk.Button( master, text = v, command = make_keys( v )).grid( row = 0, column = col )
    return 'break'

text.bind( '<KeyPress-F5>', get_key )
# Press F5 in the text box to open the keyboard.

root.mainloop()
```

With this option the extra window could be permanently open or a further frame in the GUI instead of a separate window.

There may be OS specific ways of doing this more neatly or options in tkinter that I don't know about but this should give some ideas to explore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Though this helped, this is not exactly what I am looking for. If I use keyboard shortcuts, I won't be able to type the text in any language I want. What I want is that the user should be able to select any language he/she wants and change the keyboard inputs according to that language. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you'll need to research how to use a different, assumed, keyboard layout within the operating system.  You seem to want to e.g. Type in a word processor with a UK keyboard but switch to a Greek keyboard to type in your GUI, using physically the same keyboard.  I've got no idea how todo that.